# Rendering only HTML from view?

Tags: python, django

Currently render_to_response returns a HttpResponse objects that holds the html, but is there a way to to just render only the HTML from a template, a dictionary, and a request from a view?

Note: the reason I want to do this is so I can nest django views in one another and include their values this way rather than include via template includes

i.e.:

menu.html:

```
<div>menu {{ text }}</div>
```

I want this:

template.html:

```
<div >...{{ menu }} </div>
```

view

```
def menu(request, ...):
    # do menu variable calculations here
    # returned html string rendered from template, request, kwargs, and variables    

def base(request, ...):
    menu = menu(request, ...) # rendered html for menu values
    render_to_response("template.html", context={"menu":menu})
```

rather than:

template.html

```
<div>{% include menu.html %}</div>
```

view

```
def base(request, ...):
    # calculate menu variable values here
    render_to_response("template.html", context=dictionary_of_menu_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is: `render_to_response` is a shortcut, and you can always call render directly on the template. This is described in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something), among other places.

```
template = loader.get_template('template.html')
context = Context(dictionary_of_items)
rendered = template.render(context)
```

However, for your use case I think [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) are probably a better fit.

Comment: are inclusion tags as efficient as regular variable templating?

Comment: There is no difference in efficiency, they work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use [django.template.loader.render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) to generate your 'menu' html. This will return you a string with the evaluated HTML.

Then, in your `template.html`, you should use the `safe` filter when evaulating your `menu` template variable.

```
<div>{{menu|safe}}</div>
```